# IEnumerable .Select() Not Working

Tags: c#, linq

Can someone see what I'm doing wrong below?  The first command returns an empty list.  Then the second command sets i = 1 (which is correct).

```
IEnumerable<Demographic> demographics2 = this
  .DemographicRecords
  .Where(item => item.Id == "7633")
  .Select(item => item);

int i = this
  .DemographicRecords
  .Where(item => item.Id == "7633")
  .Count();
```

Comment: Are you sure it is an empty list? Or is it just not executed yet? The `.Select()` method uses a `yield return`.

Comment: where is `DemographicRecords` defined?

Comment: `.Select(item => item)` does nothing.  `Where` already returns an `IEnumerable<Demographic>`.

Comment: `Select` won't do anything until you call a non-deferrred function

Comment: Rule one of programming is **literally** called "select isn't broken". https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-first-rule-of-programming-its-always-your-fault/ -- so good on you for asking where you've made a mistake.

Comment: And today is your day to learn what I've said many times:  **the value of a query expression is a query, not the results of executing the query**.

Comment: How do you know that first query returns empty set? How did you verified this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The first command returns an empty list.

No, it returns a *query*.  You need to *process* the query via a `foreach` loop or a call to `ToList` or `ToArray` to get to the actual results of the query. Evaluation functions like `Any()`, `Count()`, `Max()` etc. also process the query since they return a concrete result and not another query.

I suspect you are looking at the variable in the debugger.  Looking at Linq queries in the debugger is notoriously tricky since the query is often times just a wrapper around some concrete collection.